# Why don't you get a compiler error when assign raw types to generic types?

Tags: java, generics

I have been looking at OJCPA code snippets and I am confused why the compiler does not throw an error at the following code.

```
List l = new ArrayList();
l.add("a");
l.add("b");
l.add(1);

List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();
strList = l; //#1 - Why does the assignment compile?

for(String s: strList) {
      System.out.println(s); //#2 - It makes sense that it then throws a ClassCastException
}
```

I thought that the compiler would see List l as a raw type and because generics are invariant it would produce a compiler error, as it is not of type List< String >.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 7):

It is allowed for backwards compatibility.

Suppose that you are calling a legacy method that returns a `List` of `String`s, but it was written before generics were added to Java, so it returns a raw `List`.

You'd want this line to pass compilation :

```
List<String> strList = someOldMethodThatReturnsRawList();
```

Otherwise you'll have to keep using the raw `List` type in your new code in order to call that method.

Comment: more info here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Comment: I for one would have liked them to require a cast or some other syntax indication that the coder knew what he/she was doing. But I'm not aware of the various competing design criteria they were working with that the time, so have to trust that they had a good reason for it. :-)

Comment: So can you assign any raw type to typed class?